# Change form radio button options after each answer

Tags: css, reactjs, forms

There are forms where you have multiple choice answers where the question and the answer options changes after each answer.

Example:
A question with four different radio buttons (styled like buttons) as different options for answers and when you press one of the buttons the question changes and the text on the answers change so you get four new options for answers.

I cant find anything about this, how do you make one of these forms?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is too broad. See [ask]. This is just a matter of creating event listeners and taking action as appropriate. It has nothing to do with form types, though you might call them "data-driven" or "reactive".

Comment: @isherwood The question is how to make the form questions change after a choice is picked.

Comment: I didn't say unclear. I said broad. Asking how to build a large portion of a React app isn't appropriate here. Did you read that page? Asking for off-site resources is also off topic.

Comment: @random1234, I think you want to clear the selected radio and , update the questions with options ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of something you've seen?

Comment: I think you need a multiple step form. If you want to do it just on the FE you can for instance add multiple fieldset, each with a question and answers. Then with css you add display: none to all of the fieldsets. With JS you create `activeStep` variable, which will correspond to the visible question + answers (fieldset). When the user enters an answer you can update the variable and show / hide the fieldsets so only the currently active is visible. If you google "multistep form" i think you will find some good information, for instance https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do something called as conditional rendering. You can check more about it on google, there are enough articles and tutorials based on conditional rendering a form.